# Cant read files from src/main/resources folder Java 8

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, java-stream

I have package as follows

```
src->main->java->com->Sample.java
src->main->resources->orders.csv
```

and

```
src->test->java->com->SampleTest.java
src->test->resources->orders.csv
```

In Sample.java and SampleTest.java I have the following code

```
String file1 = "orders.csv";
Stream<String> lines1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1)); // Line 1
```

But i don't think code on Line 1 and Line 2 work. It does not find the file. Am i setting file1 and file2 correct?

Comment: Since `trades.csv` and `symbols.txt` are not `orders.xml` I would guess not.

Comment: HI Eliiott, i have edited my question. orders.csv is the file I am trying to access

Comment: Let's double check, are you using maven? Exactly how are you running this?

Comment: Sample.java has main method. I run it as java application and SampleTest is a junit test , i run it as Junit test

Comment: remove your resources folder, then try calling mkdirs() to create the resources folder programmatically. see if the folder gets created in the location you expect or not. I have a feeling the file1 is pointing to elsewhere (might be created at the same level as your src ).

Comment: `src` won't exist once you've packaged you App, this means that `src->main->resources->orders.csv` is an invalid path.  Instead you need to use `Class#getResource`

Comment: Add 'com' folder to both resource locations (i.e. 'src/main/resources/com' and 'src/test/resources/com') and move the '.csv' files there.

Comment: I see `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `test/main/java` and `test/main/resources`.   Are you, perchance using maven?  Or gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Because these are resource files, you want to use [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) to search for the file relative to your class and get its absolute URL.

Your `Sample.java` will look like this:

```
String file1 = "/main/resources/orders.csv";
Stream<String> lines1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(Sample.class.getResource(file1).toURI()));
```

And your `SampleTest.java` will look like this:

```
String file1 = "/test/resources/orders.csv";
Stream<String> lines1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(Sample.class.getResource(file1).toURI()));
```

Now let my explain the syntax of the string "`file1`". If you look at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), you'll see that it says:

> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

This basically means that the path provided, if it begins with a forward slash, is to be processed relative to your source directory. In other words, everything after the first forwards slash is a 
"subpath" of your source path. If there was no forward slash, the JVM would search for a package called "main" in the package defined by the current class loader. So `"/main/resources/orders.csv"` will be processed as `"src/main/resources/orders.csv"`, and `"/test/resources/orders.csv"` as `"src/test/resources/orders.csv"`.